# How do I download and install Opera in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, opera

I've heard that we can use it. Then how can I install it because I dont see it in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: my first reply, I know its a bit late but i thought it helps [Try this](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-opera-web-browser-in-ubuntu.html) It should work.

Answer (score 19):

1. To install Opera, simply go to [their download page here](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/). Ubuntu will be auto-detected, and click on the big Download Opera button:

   [image]
2. Choose the "Open With" option, and the file will automatically open in Software Center once downloaded:

[image]

3. Click on Install in Software Center, enter your password if asked, and then Opera will be installed:

   [image]

Answer (score 6):

In terminal:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list'
sudo sh -c 'wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -'
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install opera
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work @zuberuber

Comment: OMG, i did it, and it does'nt open with ubuntu software center

Comment: and how i do it? i dont have experience @zuberuber

Comment: Thank's to izx and EliahKagan i corrected code and now it should work just fine.

Comment: when i write the second part it says "wget: invalid option -- '0' "gpg: no valid OpenPGP  data found."

Comment: worked like a charm in ``12.04``. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Detailed up-to-date  instructions are available here:

- [Opera Browser](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser) in
  the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community)
- [Can I install Opera from a
  repository?](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/841/) in the [Opera
  Knowledge Base](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/)

Quoting the Opera Knowledge Base:

> With Debian- and Ubuntu-based distros, you can use Opera's repository to ensure that your system will always have the latest stable Opera version.

You can also always get the latest version from http://www.opera.com/download/ but in that case you won't be using the native system tools (apt, aptitude, Ubuntu Software Center) to do updates.

Installing via repository is the recommended way to install Opera according to the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal.

```
wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -
```

Then:
**64 bit.**

```
wget http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/pool/non-free/o/opera-stable/opera-stable_42.0.2393.517_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_42.0.2393.517_amd64.deb
```

Replace "amd64.deb" with "i386.deb" if you work on 32 bit.