# How to install last version of Opera without losing opera-unite?

Tags: upgrade, opera

[Opera unite](http://unite.opera.com/overview/) is a feature in the Opera browser that was abandoned in Opera 12.

In Windows, keeping Opera 11 and installing v12 on top of it, or upgrading, `opera-unite` stays into the browser.

In Ubuntu, by installing the v12 deb or by upgrading to v12 after adding it to software sources ([like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/169022/47206)), `opera-unite` is lost.

Is there a way of upgrading to v12 without losing opera unite, like I was able to do in Windows?

Comment: It may be possible to do so from source, but as they will be disabling their hosting of it soon, it would all be for nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the simple way is just to use the last version of Opera (that does not have opera unite) and in parallel to use a "portable" Opera 11. That is, download the tar.gz file of Opera 11 ([here](http://get.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1164/opera-11.64-1403.i386.linux.tar.bz2)), extract into any directory, and execute opera.shell file. Of course, a shortcut (launcher,etc) could be added on the desktop or to menus. In Lubuntu, editing the opera.desktop.file, the menu  would look like this:
[image]

Of course, the solution (like the question) is limited to the period in which the server for opera-unite will still work. Hopefully, an extension would take the same functions into the future.